# How can I login to app store connect? Since an error appears prevent me to continue the process

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

[image: error message]
Hello, i am facing an issue when I try to login to app store connect. The above message appears. I contacted apple support, but no answers.

Would you please help me with this issue

Answer (score 0):

This worked with me:

1. open new account (apple ID)
2. login from Safari browser on an iPhone
3. try to enroll

it is now magically working! I do not know why this is happening!